# How to replicate cURL and python's 'requests' library in PHP?

Tags: php, python, curl, python-requests

I have following code in Python that is working good (have access):

```
import requests
username = 'user'
password = 'pass'   

r = requests.get('https://internalwebsite/list', auth=(username, password))

j = r.json()
```

How do I write that in PHP?

I tried similiar like this but no success so far:

```
$postvars = "username=user&password=pass";

$url = "https://internalwebsite/list";

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);                //0 for a get request
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,3);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
print "curl response is:" . $response;
curl_close ($ch);
```

Regular cURL command works good as well (has response):

```
curl -u 'user:pass' https://internalwebsite/list
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be using the CURLOPT_USERPWD, instead of submitting the postvars for this particular use case(based on your comment to my previous solution)

```
$url = "https://internalwebsite/list";

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myusername:mypassword");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,3);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
print "curl response is:" . $response;
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Yeah - I tried with '1' flag as well and did not work (0 was just leftover from last test). I am getting unauthorized 401 error. Not sure why since from same command line cURL works fine (for same user/pass).

Comment: Edited it, to use the CURLOPT_USERPWD instead of sending postvars. Try that, and let me know the results.

Comment: Amended again; try it as is above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `HTTP POST` by `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` instead of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);` if you are using POST. Try this

```
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
$url = 'https://internalwebsite/list';

//init curl
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the URL to work with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Set the post parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user=' . $username . '&pass=' . $password);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,3);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
print "curl response is:" . $response;
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Keep getting this error:
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>

Why would that be if regular cURL with the same user/pass and exact same URL works fine?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, ( $url . '?' . $postvars ) );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo "response is $response";
```